# How do I get back to the start page with a button?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop a game app. At the gameover screen, I want to have a button that goes back to the start when you click it. But the problem is, it doesn't work. I really don't know why it doesn't work, I have tried everything but can't find the problem. Can someone help me?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class GameOver extends AppCompatActivity  {
    MediaPlayer gameoversound;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameover);
    Button weiter_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.weiter);
    weiter_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) { goToMainActivity(); }
        });


}





private void goToMainActivity() {
    Intent back = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(back);
}


}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how exactly it doesn't work? Do you get a crash? What does the logcat show?

Comment: The emulator runs the app, it doesn't crash or anything, but it straight up doesn't work. I can click it, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Can you confirm that the code inside `goToMainActivity` is executed? You can debug it and set a breakpoint or add a `Log.d(…` to check if something gets printed to the log there.
Your code looks fine so far.

Comment: it doesn't print anything to the log, i'm honestly clueless why nothing happens.

Comment: Severall things you can check: Is `weiter_button` the correct button or should the click listener be assigned to some other button on your layout? Is `weiter_button` disabled or not clickable for some other reason?

Comment: weiter_button is the correct button, I checked that several times and went over it again and again. I don't know if it's not clickable for some other reason, I'm pretty new to android studio but I wrote the same code with other buttons in another class and it works perfectly fine there.

Comment: @devinlalinvega  Can you share your Xml File .? May be you put some view above button . this is one  reason  for onclick not working .

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gameover">`

Comment: `<Button
        android:id="@+id/weiter"
        android:layout_width="151dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="@string/btn_weiter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.894" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

- Change `this` to `GameOver.this`
- You don't have to cast widgets explicitly anymore, except for some special cases. It has been this way for a while.
- If the game is over, you'd best insert a `finish();` after launching the main Activity. You don't want users to be able to go back to the gameover screen by pressing the back button.
- Set up FLAGS for your Intents. This comes in handy because if you didn't `finish();` some Activity it remains in the stack, so it will be launching that one, but then you might want a new one. This will cause issues in navigation.
- Add/ check your `onBackPressed()` methods for the 2 Activities.
- Furthermore, specify that you are overriding the method

> ```
> @Override
> public void onClick(View view)
> {
>
> }
> ```

- In the XML, `<Button>` tag, add

> ```
> android:clickable=true
> android:focusable=true
> ```